# React : retrieve the state of a child component

Tags: reactjs, react-props

I am trying to retrieve the value of the input in my `Input` component, to assign it to my user object in the parent component.

Here is my user object and my JSX:

```
const Form = ({ form }) => {
  const [inputValue, setInputValue] = useState("");

  const user = {
    user_firstname: "OO",
    user_lastname: "OO",
    user_email: "lOOl0jyyv",
    user_password: "OO"
  };

  return (
    <form className="form" onSubmit={callApi}>
      <Input
        key={uuidv4()}
        className="input_container"
        type="text"
        placeholder="Prénom"
        id="firstname"
        name="firstname"
        min="2"
        max="40"
      />
      <Input
        key={uuidv4()}
        className="input_container"
        type="text"
        placeholder="Nom"
        id="lastname"
        name="lastname"
        min="2"
        max="60"
      />
      <Input
        key={uuidv4()}
        className="input_container"
        type="email"
        placeholder="Votre adresse mail"
        id="email"
        name="email"
      />
      <Input
        key={uuidv4()}
        className="input_container"
        type="password"
        placeholder="Mot de passe"
        id="password"
        name="password"
        min="10"
        max="32"
      />
      <Input
        key={uuidv4()}
        className="input_container"
        type="password"
        placeholder="Confirmez le mot de passe"
        id="verify-password"
        name="verify-password"
        min="10"
        max="32"
      />
      <Button name="Inscription" />
    </form>
  );
};
```

Each  has its own state, I would like to be able to retrieve it from the parent component to assign them to my "user" object. This is my Input component :

```
const Input = ({
  className,
  type,
  id,
  name,
  placeholder,
  min,
  max,
  icon1,
  icon2
}) => {
  const inputHandler = e => {
    setInputValue(e.target.value);
  };

  const [inputValue, setInputValue] = useState("");

  return (
    <div className={className}>
      <input
        className="testt"
        type={type}
        id={id}
        name={name}
        placeholder={placeholder}
        minLength={min}
        maxLength={max}
        required
        value={inputValue}
        onChange={inputHandler}
      />
      {icon1 && (
        <div className="icons_container">
          <FontAwesomeIcon icon={icon1} />
          <FontAwesomeIcon icon={icon2} />
        </div>
      )}
    </div>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not define the **state** in the **parent element**, then pass a reference to the state in the **props of the child**? In your case, place the input state of all the `<Input />` components in the `<Form />` component and pass each state to its respective **input field**.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass `onChange` handler function as a prop from parent to child. This function will set value for `user` when child (Input) component invokes the function.

Changes needed for parent component:

```
...
  const [user, setUser] = React.useState({
    user_firstname: "OO",
    user_lastname: "OO",
    user_email: "lOOl0jyyv",
    user_password: "OO"
  });

  return (
    <form className="form" onSubmit={callApi}>
      <Input
        key={uuidv4()}
        className="input_container"
        type="text"
        placeholder="Prénom"
        id="firstname"
        name="firstname"
        min="2"
        max="40"
        onChange={value => setUser({ ...user, user_firstname: value })}
      />
...
```

Changes needed for `Input` component:

```
const Input = ({
  className,
  type,
  id,
  name,
  placeholder,
  min,
  max,
  icon1,
  icon2,
  onChange
}) => {
  const inputHandler = e => {
    setInputValue(e.target.value);
    onChange(e.target.value);
  };
...
```